# IBM Chatbot Assistant - How to skip to the next slot

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have a node in which I have enabled **slots** and within the node there are several **slots**. The first slot asks the customer to provide a specific number. After 3 unsuccessful inputs, I want the bot to automatically skip to the next slot. Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can exit or move on after a certain number of unsuccessful attempts of gathering information. This is done using the "Not Found" condition on slots and by adding a counter variable. Check out this example in the docs on "[Moving on after multiple failed attempts](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-slots.html#slots-stop-trying-after-3)".

That sample defines this counter (my recommendation: name it differently):

```
  "context": {
    "counter": "<? context['counter'] + 1 ?>"
  }
```

Then, in a "not found" condition, you would check `$counter > 3`. There, in the output and context section, set up another context variable to trigger skipping to a specific node.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you are the king of this site ! I appreciate your help!!!

Comment: By the way, I need to set the initial value of "counter" to 0, how can I do it? I have tried many ways but failed..

Comment: The docs suggest to set it in an earlier node. Another option could be to use the ternary operator (https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#conditions-and-predicates-in-the-response) and check if counter exists and increment, else set it to 0